How do you do streaming ECIES encryption in Rust?
I've been looking at the official ECIES crate and the encrypt/decrypt methods take a &[u8] and return Result<Vec<u8>, Error>, which means the entire message has to be in memory. In C# + .NET you can do this using the Stream type, where you wrap a Stream in a CryptoStream wrapper and just write to it, so you can copy between e.g. FileStreams to encrypt on disk. Does Rust have any equivalent to this? If not, how do I encrypt a file that is too large to fit in memory?

What do you mean by "official" in "the official ECIES crate"? Is there a reason you can't use a different crate?

I looked at the other crates and none of them appear to support streaming cryptography
